# Scrollbar not displayed flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart

Scrollbar not displayed in flutter web.
 my second try is:

```
Widget getSecondStep() {
        return  DraggableScrollbar.arrows(
          controller: ScrollController(),
          child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[BlaBlaBla(), BlaBla()],
                ),
              ],
            ),
        );
      }
```

and my first try was:

```
Widget getSecondStep() {
        return  Scrollbar(
          controller: ScrollController(),
          child: ListView(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: <Widget>[BlaBlaBla(), BlaBla()],
                ),
              ],
            ),
        );
      }
```

i'm trying to change theme color but it didn't work.

finally, `flutter doctor -v`

```
 [√] Flutter (Channel beta, v1.14.6, on Microsoft Windows [Version
 10.0.18362.657], locale en-US)
     • Flutter version 1.14.6 at C:\flutter_windows_v1.9.1+hotfix.2-stable\flutter
     • Framework revision fabeb2a16f (4 weeks ago), 2020-01-28 07:56:51 -0800
     • Engine revision c4229bfbba
     • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.5.0 fc3af737c7)


 [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK
 version 29.0.2)
     • Android SDK at C:\Users\moshi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
     • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
     • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
     • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)
     • All Android licenses accepted.

 [√] Chrome - develop for the web
     • Chrome at C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe

 [√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
     • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
     • Flutter plugin version 40.0.2
     • Dart plugin version 191.8423
     • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b03)

 [!] VS Code (version 1.42.1)
     • VS Code at C:\Users\moshi\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code
     X Flutter extension not installed; install from
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

 [√] Connected device (2 available)
     • Chrome     • chrome     • web-javascript • Google Chrome 79.0.3945.130
     • Web Server • web-server • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

 ! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: could you post your "flutter doctor -v"?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you find any solution for this?

Comment: no i don't find

Answer (score 8):

EDIT: MAY 2021 UPDATE:
Scrollbar should be visible by default since Flutter 2.2

---

OLD ANSWER:

Wrap a `ListView` with `Scrollbar` and use the same scroll controller like this:

```dart
          Scrollbar(
            isAlwaysShown: true,
            controller: _scrollController,
            child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scrollController,
                itemCount: 100,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    title: Text("Item: ${index + 1}"),
                  ));
                }),
          ),
```

Comment: I had to hook up the scroll controller to both, this was my issue. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

This is the 'intended' functioning. Remember, web is still in beta, and currently most Flutter Web apps look and behave like Android Material/iOS apps, which obviously don't have a scrollbar.
For the same reason, you can click and drag using the mouse, and the page will move up and down.

There is currently a GitHub issue opened on this topic [(which you can find at this link)](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40107). Bear in mind it is a feature request.

EDIT: As of April 2nd, there is now configurable scrollbar support built into flutter!

Answer (score 3):

as of flutter 2.2 default behaviour for most scrollable widgets on web and desktop is to display scrollbar while scrolling and to quickly fade away the scrollbar when scrolling has ended. to persist the scrollbar after scrolling has ended wrap the scrollable widget in a theme as follows:

```
Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(scrollbarTheme: const ScrollbarThemeData(isAlwaysShown: true)),
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
       controller: scrollController,
```

Note the added scrollController to avoid conflicting positions of the PrimaryScrollController if you are using multiple scrollable widgets.

One last thing to note is that if you wish the scrollbar to be visible even before first scrolling you have to hack it somehow. My solution was to scroll programmatically after the frame has been built:

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
  scrollController.animateTo(3, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 200), curve: Curves.ease);
});
```

Hope this comes in handy some day...

Answer (score 2):

2021 March UPDATE: with Flutter 2.0, Flutter Web is now available in the Stable channel, and you can use

```
Scrollbar(controller: _scrollController, isAlwaysShown: true, child: ...
```

To display the scrollbar and interact with it :)
Just make sure the controller of your scrollbar and list is the same one.

Comment: Can you add the source of your information please? A link to the documentation or smth?

Comment: What do you mean by "Just make sure the controller of your scrollbar and list is the same one"?

Comment: The 'controller' variable being passed to the list you are scrolling and to the Scrollbar, must be the same object.

Comment: what if i'm not scrolling a list? what if it's a coloumn?

Answer (score 0):

Currently flutter web working is similar to that of a android/iOS application. It doesn't support the scrolling through scrollbar. You have to use a customized, if you want to use one for your web application then you should definitely look for the [flutter_web_scrollbar](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_scrollbar) package in [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).